# curly bracket not recognised in while function? (R on MAC)

Tags: r, macos, loops

I am trying to do some web scraping with a loop and I can not find the error in my code. The result I get is perfectly fine, but the loop doesn't get started again because of the curly bracket that seems to be wrong ...

**My Code:**

```
bereichnummer <- 10
downloadcounter <- 1

while (bereichnummer < 39) {
bereichlink <- ".basecontent-pbsbw---table:nth-child(12) i"
bereichnummer <- 10
bereichlink <-gsub(12, bereichnummer,bereichlink)
bereich <- html_nodes(webpage, bereichlink)
bereich <- gsub("<i>","", html_nodes(webpage, bereichlink))
bereich <- gsub("</i>","",bereich)

  if ((s% %% 2) != 0) {  
  kompetenzlink <- ".basecontent-pbsbw---table:nth-child(10) .even td:nth-child(1) div"
    } else {
  kompetenzlink <- gsub(".even", "odd", ".basecontent-pbsbw---table:nth-child(10) .even td:nth-child(1) div")
    }

kompetenzlink <- gsub(10, bereichnummer, kompetenzlink)

downloads <- webpage %>% html_nodes("thead+ tbody a") %>% html_attr("href")
filename <- paste(bereich, "_")
filename <- paste(filename, kompetenz)
filename <- paste(filename, ".pdf")
filename <- paste("BFS_BEJ_", filename)
filename <- gsub("[[:blank:]]","",filename)
filename

download <- webpage %>% html_node(downloads[downloadcounter]) %>% html_attr("href")
downloadpath <- paste("https://Ls-bw.de",download, sep = "")
downloadpath

bereichnummer <- bereichnummer + 2 
downloadcounter <- downloadcounter + 1
}
```

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

This means there is a } to much in the code (more specifically, the one at the end), right? But I only use it 3 times.

One time in the while () {}, one time for the if(){} and one time for else{}.

Comment: There is another one at the end.

Comment: Yes, but that is the one that actually closes the while function, isnt it?

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Does not it tell you which line you have the error?

Comment: What software are you using to run the code?

Comment: I am using R Studio

Comment: I have encountered in some case that restarting RStudio could solve such strange errors, but never used RStudion on Mac myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
if ((s% %% 2) != 0) {
```

There are one too many '%' characters.  Perhaps you mean: `if ((s%%2) != 0) {`

Comment: I fixed that, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: The exact same error message?  Or another error message?  It looks like there are some logic errors in the code as well.  For example on line 6 you have "bereichnummer <- 10" but your while loop is testing for it to be < 39, but you set it = to 10 every loop, so it will always be less than 39.  You should move "bereichnummer <- 10" outside your while() loop